# How to filter many to many field in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I have a model Election that has a 'candidates' field which is in many to many relationship with the Candidate model and a 'region' field which has one to many relationship with the Region model. Also Candidate model also has a region field which also has one to many relationship with the Region model.

Now I created a model form of model Election. My problem is how can I filter candidates which is specific to a particular region

**Here are my models and form**

```
 class Region(models.Model):
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    region_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_name

 class Candidate(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    party_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    candidate_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

 class Election(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(Admin, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    region_name = models.ForeignKey(Region, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    region_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(null=True)
    candidates = models.ManyToManyField(Candidate)
    winner = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True) 

 class NewElectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Election
        exclude = ['winner']
    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewElectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["candidates"].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
                #below query is for testing
        #region = Region.objects.get(region_name='Mumbai')
        self.fields["candidates"].queryset = region.candidate_set.all()
```

Every region has a admin which is going to post this form. Since region_name is variable here I cannot run region.candidate_set query
If the above approach is not possible then is there any other solution?

Comment: Too broad, where is the REGION variable coming from? Is it the region of the logged in user, or it will be provided by a visitor?

Answer (score 1):

Since the form will be posted by an admin of a region, and Election model has a foreign key to Admin, you can filter the Election by admin thereby giving you the candidates from the region of the admin

in your VIEW that renders this form, add a method

```
    class YourView(...):
        .....

        # This inserts 'admin' into kwargs of the form BEFORE it's loaded
        def get_form_kwargs(self):
            kwargs = super(YourView, self).get_form_kwargs()
            kwargs['admin'] = self.request.user
            return kwargs


    class NewElectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Election
            exclude = ['winner']
        def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):

            #instanciate the admin variable that you inserted into kwargs
            admin = kwargs.pop('admin')
            super(NewElectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields["candidates"].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
            self.fields["candidates"].queryset = Election.objects.filter(admin=admin)
```

OR
If your Admin model has Region field

```
        def get_form_kwargs(self):
            kwargs = super(YourView, self).get_form_kwargs()
            kwargs['region'] = self.request.user.region
            return kwargs
```

then query the Candidate model as

```
    class NewElectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Election
            exclude = ['winner']
        def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):

            #instanciate the region variable that you inserted into kwargs
            region = kwargs.pop('region')
            super(NewElectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields["candidates"].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
            self.fields["candidates"].queryset = Candidate.objects.filter(region=region)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Candidate.objects.filter(region__region_name="Mumbai")
```

The above query will give you all the candidates with region="Mumbai"